# How to make PageUp/PageDown/Home/End work correctly when using putty to connect to Mac OSX

Tags: macos, putty

I recently got to maintain an OSX server box . I usually use Putty (on Windows XP) to connect to Linux boxes , and it works well . PageUp/PageDown/Home/End all work in vi and pico.

But when I connect to this OSX box , all these four keys not work in vim (7.2.108) but work well in pico ...

How to make them work in vim ?

Here are some settings FYI :

```
smallufo@miniserver:~ $ echo $TERM
xterm

smallufo@miniserver:~ $ locale
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=

smallufo@miniserver:~ $ uname -a
Darwin miniserver.local 10.4.1 Darwin Kernel Version 10.4.1: Wed May 12 21:34:51 PDT 2010; root:xnu-1504.7.50~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64


smallufo@miniserver:~ $ set
BASH=/bin/bash
BASH_ARGC=()
BASH_ARGV=()
BASH_LINENO=()
BASH_SOURCE=()
BASH_VERSINFO=([0]="3" [1]="2" [2]="48" [3]="1" [4]="release" [5]="x86_64-apple-darwin10.0")
BASH_VERSION='3.2.48(1)-release'
```

Hope these help...